# git-commit problem in Maven release plugin

Tags: git, maven, gitlab-ci, maven-release-plugin

How can configure maven release plugin to set  user.email ??

I also add .gitconfig like this

```
[user]
    name = azizkhani
    email = aa.azizkhani@gmail.com
    username = aa.azizkhani
```

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project wm: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR]   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal:********@runner-wefvk5ml-project-17780475-concurrent-0.(none)')
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Did you try the commands which git shows? `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` and `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

Comment: I run maven release plugin in gitlab cicd by mvn command

Comment: Maven plugin execute git command and i dont know how set git config in this plugin

Answer (score 2):

the maven release plugin use globale git config so you have to set globale user config as the error is saying by running

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```